# [symfony2]Wamp + sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, wamp

I use symfony2 on Wamp which is connect on a SQL server DB. (yes, I cry )

When i start project with

```
php app/console server:run
```

it's all good, it's slow, but my website is ok on 127.0.0.1:8000, Doctrine2 connect to the sql-server DB without a problem.

my problem : when i go on localhost/MyProject/web/app_php.php (means that i use wamp and not 'server:run').
Symfony throw a exception : PDOException : could not find driver. I suffer for days to install those drivers on wamp/bin/php5.x.x/etc.

for more details, I install :

-basic wamp : Apache : 2.4.9 MySQL : 5.6.17 PHP : 5.5.12 PHPMyAdmin : 4.1.14 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.5

-Symfony 2.6.5

-php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

-php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

-Change the php ini and add those dll to extension.

-install IIS and Microsoft ODBC Driver 11  as require microsoft here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

***I don't know what i miss***. how can it work with server:run and not with Wamp...?

Windows will kill me soon.

Comment: WAMP has two `php.ini` files, have you updated the correct one?

Comment: Yes i did. Nevermind, i found the pb. it's 32x and 64x incompatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it : I use 'server:run' with a 32bit wamp version while localhost was on 64bit wamp version...

Well. Windows dll

->http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

work only for 32 BIT version or Wamp !!! Some people said on forum they managed to make it work on 64bit. I just failed and uninstall 64bit version of Wamp